# Linq Group By with select

Tags: asp.net, identity

```
public class PowerPlantsBudgetUsage
    {
        public int PowerPlantID { get; set; }
       public int TotalWork { get; set; }
        public int ElectricalWorkNo { get; set; }
        public int MechanicalWorkNo { get; set; }
        public int CivilWorkNo { get; set; }
        public int AdminWorkNo { get; set; }
        public int VehicleWorkNo { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public List<string> PowerPlantNameList { get; set; }
    }

 public IActionResult Total()
        {
            var query = _context.REHPData.Include(r => r.PowerPlants).Include(r => r.WorkCategories).GroupBy(r => r.PowerPlantID).Select(s => new PowerPlantsBudgetUsage
            {
                PowerPlantID = s.Key,
                TotalWork = s.Count(),
                ElectricalWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 1),
                MechanicalWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 2),
                CivilWorkNo = s.Count(x => x.WorkCategoriesID == 3),
                AdminWorkNo=s.Count(x=>x.WorkCategoriesID==4),
                VehicleWorkNo=s.Count(x=>x.WorkCategoriesID==6),          
                Total = s.Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                PowerPlantNameList = s.Select(x => x.PowerPlants.PowerPlantName).ToList()

            }).ToList();
            return View(query);
[enter image description here][1]
        }
```

my problems is PowerPlantNameList  is show Totalwork count number 
example totalwork is 5
powrplantname is test test test test test so on...

[My View Result is Look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObKoW.png)

Comment: Yes your code is normal, waht do you expect ? What output result do you want ?

Comment: Reply for thank you.I want output is PowerPlantName column  is one Powerpalnt result.But my output is https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObKoW.png

Comment: Don't understand sorry ... have you an image or text table example of desired output result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well you want to display only first `PowerPlantName` in your colmun. So change the property `PowerPlantNameList` to :

```
public string PowerPlantName { get; set; }
```

And affect it with :

```
[...]
Total = s.Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
PowerPlantName = s.Select(p => p.PowerPlants.PowerPlantName).First()
```

Comment: your code changed error is cannot convert type string to bool this part(x.PowerPlants.PowerPlantName) please help me teachers

Comment: Thank You Teacher.

Comment: Please help me sir lasted comment in my result how to create model and linq query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987400/how-to-relationship-tables-in-groupby-and-sum-row-and-column-and-where-asp-rout?noredirect=1#comment83158610_47987400