# How to relationship tables in groupby and sum row and column and Where (asp-route-id)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First Table is Power Plant Name List Table

```
public class PowerPlants
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }       

        [Required]
        public string PowerPlantName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PowerPlantShortName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PowerPlantCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BudgetYearlyAllocation> BudgetYearlyAllocation { get; set; }
       }
```

Second Table is BudgetYear Table

```
public class BudgetYear
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BudgetYearName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BudgetYearlyAllocation> BudgetYearlyAllocation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }

    }
```

Three is Budge Allocation Table. This table data is ever calander yearly assign budget allocation for our plants.But not see client user for this data.

```
public class BudgetYearlyAllocation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }


        // This is Budget Head of our departments for power plants
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaTeen { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaTwo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaFour { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaFive { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaSix { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaSeven { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal AdminThaTwoOneSeven{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaOneOneFour { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaTwo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaFour { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaFiveOne { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaFiveTwo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaSeven { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaEight { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaNine { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal MachineThaOneOneSeven { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal CapitalThaThreeOne { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal CapitalThaFourOne { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal CapitalThaFourThree { get; set; }

        //This is client user assign for relationship dropdown list add or not add this Part  relationship please help me.......
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

       //relationship for BudgetYearID
        public int BudgetYearID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetYearID")]
        public virtual BudgetYear BudgetYear { get; set; }

        // relationship for powerplantID
        public int PowerPlantID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PowerPlantID")]
        public virtual PowerPlants PowerPlants { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
    }
```

Four user data input table is

```
public class REHPViewModelData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? DLPermit { get; set; }
        public string WANo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string WorkNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]     
       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? WorkDurationStartDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]     
       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? WorkDurationEnadDate { get; set; }
       [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal SubmittedAmount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal ApprovedAmount { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReachDateToREHP { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReachDateToCE { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReachDateToMD { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReachDateToEPGEEC { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReachDateToMOEE { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? ReachDateToMOEEEC { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? BudgetSubmitDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]

       [DisplayFormat( DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? BudgetPermitDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
        public decimal? PermittedAmount { get; set; }

        public string UploadFilePath { get; set; }

        //Relationship for PowerPlantID
        public int PowerPlantID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PowerPlantID")]
        public virtual PowerPlants PowerPlants { get; set; }

        //Relationship for BudgetHeadID
        public int BudgetHeadID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetHeadID")]
        public virtual BudgetHead BudgetHead { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CurrencyID")]
        public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int WorkCategoriesID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("WorkCategoriesID")]
        public virtual WorkCategories WorkCategories { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ConfirmID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ConfirmID")]
        public virtual Confirm Confirm { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AuthorityID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AuthorityID")]
        public virtual BudgetAuthority BudgetAuthority { get; set; }

       //Relationship of budgetyearID
        [Required]
        public int BudgetYearID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetYearID")]
        public virtual BudgetYear BudgetYear { get; set; }

        //Relationship of budgetyearAllocationID this part is add or not add  please advice because yearly budget allocation amount of powerplants - used budgethead amount and for calculation sum column and row.
        public int BudgetYearAllocationID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BudgetYearAllocationID")]
        public virtual BudgetYearlyAllocation BudgetYearlyAllocation{ get; set; }

    }
```

Five BudgetHead Table this table of BudgetHeadName column of data is equal to BudgetYearlyAllocation table in decimal properties .This table relationship to BudgetYearlyAllocation need or not.

```
public class BudgetHead
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BudgetHeadName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string BudgetHeadDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<REHPViewModelData> REHPData { get; set; }
    }
```

Then my HomeController of BudgetResultTable() in LINQ With groupby of PlantName and

```
public IActionResult BudgetResultTable(int id)
        {

            var query = _context.REHPData.Include(r => r.PowerPlants).Where(r=>r.BudgetYearID == id).GroupBy(r => r.PowerPlantID).Select(s => new BudgetResultTable
            {
                PowerPlantID = s.Key,
                PowerPlantName = s.Select(p => p.PowerPlants.PowerPlantName).First(),
                //Powerplants of budget head with yearly allocation from BudgetYearlyAllocationTable data
                AdminThaTeen = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTeen).First(),
                AdminThaTwo = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwo).First(),
                AdminThaFour = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFour).First(),
                AdminThaFive = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFive).First(),
                AdminThaSix = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaSix).First(),
                AdminThaSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaSeven).First(),
                AdminThaTwoOneSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwoOneSeven).First(),
                MachineThaOneOneFour = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaOneOneFour).First(),
                MachineThaTwo = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaTwo).First(),
                MachineThaFour = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaFour).First(),
                MachineThaFiveOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaFiveOne).First(),
                MachineThaFiveTwo = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaFiveTwo).First(),
                MachineThaSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaSeven).First(),
                MachineThaEight = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaEight).First(),
                MachineThaNine = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaNine).First(),
                MachineThaOneOneSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaOneOneSeven).First(),
                CapitalThaThreeOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.CapitalThaThreeOne).First(),
                CapitalThaFourOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.CapitalThaFourOne).First(),
                CapitalThaFourThree = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.CapitalThaFourThree).First(),

                //used admin categories budget usage part
                UsedAdminThaTeen = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 7).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedAdminThaTwo = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 9).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedAdminThaFour = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 10).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedAdminThaFive = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 11).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedAdminThaSix = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 12).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedAdminThaSeven = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 13).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedAdminThaTwoOneSeven = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 14).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),

                //used machine categories budget usage part
                UsedMachineThaOneOneFour = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 16).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaTwo = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 17).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaFour = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 18).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaFiveOne = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 19).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaFiveTwo = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 20).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaSeven = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 21).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaEight = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 22).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaNine = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 23).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedMachineThaOneOneSeven = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 24).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),

                //used capital categories budget usage part
                UsedCapitalThaThreeOne = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 25).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedCapitalThaFourOne = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 26).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                UsedCapitalThaFourThree = s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 27).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),

                //Balance admin categories budget usage part
                BalanceAdminThaTeen = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTeen).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 7).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceAdminThaTwo = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwo).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 9).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceAdminThaFour = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFour).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 10).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceAdminThaFive = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFive).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 11).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceAdminThaSix = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaSix).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 12).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceAdminThaSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaSeven).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 13).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceAdminThaTwoOneSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwoOneSeven).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 14).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),

                //Balance machine categories budget usage part
                BalanceMachineThaOneOneFour = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaOneOneFour).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 16).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaTwo = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaTwo).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 17).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaFour = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaFour).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 18).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaFiveOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaFiveOne).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 19).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaFiveTwo = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaFiveTwo).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 20).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaSeven).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 21).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaEight = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaEight).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 22).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaNine = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaNine).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 23).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceMachineThaOneOneSeven = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.MachineThaOneOneSeven).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 24).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),

                //Balance capital categories budget usage part
                BalanceCapitalThaThreeOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.CapitalThaThreeOne).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 25).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceCapitalThaFourOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.CapitalThaFourOne).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 26).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),
                BalanceCapitalThaFourThree = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.CapitalThaFourThree).First() - s.Where(x => x.BudgetHeadID == 27).Sum(x => x.ApprovedAmount),




                //How to sum total Column Calculation error this part  using columnone ienumbeable not support therefor need partical view in table footer. 
                //ColumnOne = s.Select(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTeen).Sum()
                // ColumnTwo = s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaTwo),
                // ColumnThree= s.Sum(x => x.BudgetYearlyAllocation.AdminThaFour)



            }).ToList();           
            return View(query);
        }
```

Please help me design of budgetyearllyallocation class and rehpdata clas and how to sum column of groupby powrplants with budgetallocation amount.Confuse

Comment: Please help me sir..........

Comment: Cut down your code to the bare minimum that describes your problem sufficiently. And then describe the problem clearly. How can we help you design classes if we don't know what you're aiming at?

Comment: Thank sir my problems define powerplants constant amount ever yearly.This amount of each budgethead compare from rehpdata table of  Budgethead with used approved amount sum row and column. route by yearlytable id in rehpdatatable.Please answer my problem sir.

Comment: I think it might be nicer to uses types in the 'BudgetYearlyAllocation' instead of a new field every time... Cut it down to: 'Id, Type, Value'. The queries might go a lot easier..

Comment: I want PowerPlantName BudgetYear BudgetHead AllocateAmount UsedAmount Different 2017 P1 B1 1000 800 200                        how to create model and groupby powerplant and rout BudgetyearId please simple model and linq query

Comment: I think sum of BudgetResultTable ViewMode for         var TotalAdminThaTeen =BudgetResultTable.Sum(x=>AdminThaTeen); #othercolumn sum for this query style how do you think teachers.